# Take all the objects from the array, and set their properties from another array

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, properties

please help me with basic question:

I have array of objects (suppose it's array  of views). And another array (suppose it colors.) i'am looking convenient way to take all object from first array and sequentially set property (setBackgroundColor) from another array. Here is my cod;

```
    @interface ViewController ()

_arrayWithColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor purpleColor], nil];

_arrayWithViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:view1,view2,view3,view4, nil];

    for (int i = 0; i<[_arrayWithViews count];i++ ) {
        [[_arrayWithViews objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[self setColor:i]];
        [self.view addSubview:[_arrayWithViews objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}
-(UIColor*)setColor:(NSInteger) index  {
  _arrayWithColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor purpleColor], nil];
    return [_arrayWithColors objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

I create method that returns a color from another array. 
Maybe someone knows a better way to do this operation?

Comment: There's not much value to the setColor method and none to the line that re-creates the color array each time you reference it.  To be safe you should check that there are at least as many colors as views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate @PhillipMills comment, you should create your color array once and check to make sure the index is within the bounds of the color array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _arrayWithViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:view1,view2,view3,view4, nil];

    for (int i = 0; i<[_arrayWithViews count];i++ ) {
        [[_arrayWithViews objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[self getColor:i]];
        [self.view addSubview:[_arrayWithViews objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray*)arrayWithColors {
    if (!_arrayWithColors){
        self.arrayWithColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor purpleColor], nil];
    }
    return _arrayWithColors;
}

- (UIColor*)getColor:(NSUInteger)index {
    UIColor* color = [UIColor whiteColor]; //default view color
    if (index < self.arrayWithColors.count){
        color =  [self.arrayWithColors objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return color;
}
```